# WebElement text empty for most but not all rows when parsing through a table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape options data from Yahoo Finance pages. I've managed to extract the necessary table, and peeking through debugger shows everything correctly populated in DOM. However, when trying to print out the cell values, I get empty text after a certain number of rows.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=600,800")
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

browser.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/options?p=AMZN&straddle=true')

puts_table = browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
puts_body = puts_table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody')
rows = puts_body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
    col_str = ''
    for col in cols:
        col_str = col_str + repr(col.text) + ' '
    print(col_str, flush=True)
```

```
'46.55' '+2.37' '+5.36%' '10' '400' '50.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '1' '6,205'
'36.87' '0.00' '-' '10' '12' '51.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '50' '50'
'46.03' '+14.48' '+45.90%' '5' '136' '52.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '1' '12,652'
'45.20' '+8.28' '+22.43%' '1' '62' '53.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '1' '8,452'
'28.85' '0.00' '-' '4' '364' '54.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '64' ''
'41.94' '+1.96' '+4.90%' '1' '457' '55.00' '0.01' '0.00' '-' '1' ''
'26.15' '' '' '3' '61' '' '0.01' '' '' '4' ''
'' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
'' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
'' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
'' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' '' ''
```

As you can see, after a few rows all elements return ''. Any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

What I tried:

- repr'ing everything in case the symbols in values are causing print formatting issues
- sleep for 10 secs after get, in case the script is running ahead of the site.
- iterating in reverse. Same like above..it prints a handful of rows and then all cells become ''

Comment: Why not use something like [`yfinance`](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) instead of trying to scrape the site?

Comment: Bummer, I don't know how I missed that when I was searching around. Thanks for the pointer!